# Optimizing Image Processing in Flutter for Pose Estimation in Python Backend

Tags: python, flutter, dart, image-processing, optimization

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using image processing to generate an RGB array that serves as input for a pose estimation model. Each frame from a camera (now I am trying only every 20 frames, but still very laggy) feed is being converted into pose estimation coordinates. I'm aiming to optimize this process for better performance.

Here's how I'm handling the HTTP request:

```
    _controller.startImageStream(
    (CameraImage img) async {
      frameCount += 1;
      if (frameCount % 20 == 0) {
        final start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        final rgbArray = convertYUV420toRGBArray(img);
        if (rgbArray != null) {
          final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(rgbArray), headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
         # ...

          print(response.body);
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
      }
    },
```

That's how I am transferring the CameraImage to an rgb array

```
List<List<List<int>>>? convertYUV420toRGBArray(CameraImage image) {
try {
  final int width = image.width;
  final int height = image.height;
  final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final int? uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel;

  List<List<List<int>>> rgbList = [];

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    List<List<int>> row = [];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      final int uvIndex = (uvPixelStride! * (x / 2).floor()) + (uvRowStride * (y / 2).floor());
      final int index = y * width + x;

      final int yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
      final int up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
      final int vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

      int r = (yp + (vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179)).round().clamp(0, 255);
      int g = (yp - (up * 46549 / 131072) + 44 - (vp * 93604 / 131072) + 91).round().clamp(0, 255);
      int b = (yp + (up * 1814 / 1024 - 227)).round().clamp(0, 255);

      row.add([r, g, b]);
    }
    rgbList.add(row);
  }
  return rgbList;
} catch (e) {
  print("Error>>> $e");
  return null;
}
```

}

Theoretically it would be possible to transfer it to a png, jpg and then send this to my python backend, and encoding it there, but firstly it seems for my research that you have to do more computational workload then when you just trying to convert CameraImage to an rgb array. Of course this array is not compressed at all.

This is how I handle the rgb array in my backend.

```
# POST method
def handle_estimate_pose():
    frame_array = request.get_json()  # Get the image from the POST request
    np_arr = np.array(frame_array).astype(np.uint8)
    # ...
```

Thank you for your time and I would really appreciate if someone could help me here out. :)

Comment: (assuming whole processing can be done in Python) 1) use `numpy` arrays instead of list of lists, 2) try to vectorize your code using numpy 3) if seconds step seems impossible, take a look at `numba` package.

Comment: Thats seems like a good idea. Thank you I will try that.